# How to Integrate SFDC with Java Application

Tags: apex, integration

I am new to Integration.  I have a requirement where I need to integrate salesforce to Java application

Java Application : It has only 2 fields.This is used to generate license key and Registration key.  This keys are used for installing the software.

SFDC :  I have to create a button and add 2 custom fields. On click of button it should call the java application, generate the license and Registration key and display on SFDC fields.

They are not publishing it as web service.  Can someone tell me the best approach for this integration?

Is it possible to call an java class for apex, or we should use rest api? Kindly suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can't call Java directly. You'll want to expose your Java app as a REST service that's available to the Internet (e.g. public-facing) so that you can use Apex Code or even JavaScript to call the service.